# Android не отображаются картинки на реальном телефоне

Tags: android, android-imageview

Добрый день.Картинки гружу с базы данных.В эмуляторе все нормально, при подключении телефона - пусто.
Вот разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Адаптер

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Movie> movies;


public MoviesAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movies) {
    this.context = context;
    this.movies = movies;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    Picasso.with(context).load(movies.get(position).getImageLink()).into(holder.imageView);
    //Glide.with(context).load(movies.get(position).getImageLink()).into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movies.size();
}

public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();

        switch (position) {
            case 0 : Intent intentAbout = new Intent(context,AboutActivity.class);
                     context.startActivity(intentAbout);
                     break;
```

Загрузка

```
private void getMoviesFromDB(int id) {

    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... movieIds) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://*.*.*.*/main_scr.php?id=" + movieIds[0])
                    //.url("http://*.*.*.*/main_scr.php?id=" + movieIds[0])
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    Movie movie = new Movie(object.getInt("id"), object.getString("scr_image"));

                    MainActivity.this.movies.add(movie);
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Пробовал и Пикассо и глайд, результ такой же.Спасибо.

Comment: Только начал изучать.Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос : Как?

Comment: Т.е. не использовать CardView ? Или как? Можно пример на моей разметке?

Comment: проблема не в том, что на эмуляторе высокоскоростная выделенная линия, а в телефоне медленный мобильный интернет? может просто не успевает прогрузиться

Comment: при подключенном через юсб телефоне картинки не прорисовываются. Телефон подключен через свой вай-фай, дальше оптика. На главном окне их всего 3 шт. по 50к каждая.Приложение реагирует, переключается с активности на активность, а картинок нет, хотя надписи видны. В эмуляторе все нормально. Второй день мучаюсь. :((

Comment: Такая же ерунда была только с вьюпейджером. Помогло полное удаление приложения с телефона и перезагрузка его. Как бы это банально не звучало.

Comment: Удалял приложение, перегружал телефон. Все то же.:((